# Install Windows 10 UWP extension SDK using msi

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm building an extension SDK to deploy a Windows 10 UWP custom control in Visual Studio 2017.

If I pack it as .vsix and deploy it using Extension Manager, the control appears in Visual Studio toolbox and the SDK appears in Reference Manager > Universal Windows > Extensions section and Tools > Extensions > Installed > SDKs.

If I install the .vsix content (unzip and take all the files) using a msi installer and deploy the files to a custom location (the install kit includes more than just the custom control and I would like to keep all the installed content under the the same root folder) and add the registry entry as [decribed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-software-development-kit), the control appears in Visual Studio toolbox and the SDK appears in Reference Manager > Universal Windows > Extensions section but it does not appear in Tools > Extensions > Installed > SDKs. 
What else do I need to do to make the SDK appear in Tools > Extensions > Installed > SDKs when it is installed using a msi installer?